# How to get input text value in side next <td>

Tags: jquery

i want get the value of text input with the help of jquery like

```
    var myInput = $('.radio').next('td').find(".txt-email").val();
```

but i am not getting the result.

here is the html

```
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" class="radio"/>A
        <input type="radio" name="rdbtn-im" class="radio"/>B
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="txb" id="txt_im" class="txt-email" value="200"/>
    </td>
```

Comment: Which element is `this`?

Comment: What does `$(this)` refer to? Please post a complete example.

Comment: What is the cotext of `this` - `td` or `radio`? Most likely, you would need `$(this).parent().next().find('.txt-email').val()`

Answer (score 3):

Just use the ID:

```
$("#txt_im").val()
```

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine, you probably aren't getting what you expect from $(this). You either are getting it completely wrong or it's probably selecting the input.

try :

```
$(this).closest('td').next('td').find(".txt-email").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is your radio button:

```
var myInput = $(this).parent().next('td').find(".txt-email").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this` refers to your radio buttons, use:

```
$(this).closest('td').next().find(".txt-email").val()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yLsNx/)**

Answer (score 0):

`$("#txt_im").val()` would that be

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an id on the input field, you can do this which is a lot easier.

```
$('#txt_im').val();
```